# Angular 4 bind HTTP response to typescript model

Tags: angular, validation, model-binding

I have an angular 4 page which gets inputs from the user.  I do have validation on individual controls.  On submit I want to do server validations (essentially rechecking all validations) and return any errors as an array with field name, true or false and an error if it failed.

I would like these errors to map to the controls on the page and show as errors. I am using reactive forms and the server response would use the same name as the form control.

Example, control name is 'name'.  After submit I get a response back that name is invalid.  I would like to show and error message under the control.  This would be much like MVC when upon submit errors are shown next to each control.

Is this possible and how would I go about generating a generic binding that could be used for all forms.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share your code

Answer (score 0):

```
    Yes, it is quite simple in angular. Here is an example how to do so.

    1. HTML file.

    <form [formGroup]="saveForm"  (ngSubmit)="saveData()" >
        <div>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input  id="name"  type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" tabindex="1">
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="errror" >
            <p>{{errorMsg}}</p>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" id="btnSave" >Save</button>
    </form>

2.In Component ts.
a. Defined the formgroup & error message variable.
  saveForm :FormGroup;
  errror :boolean = false ;
  errorMsg :any;
b. Initialize form group. (You can defined client side validation here using angular validator)
  this.saveForm = this.fb.group({
     name: ['']
  });
c. On save data method you need to set the error bit true.
saveData() {
    let data = this.saveForm .value.name;
    this._userService.save(data)  // calling service here.
      .subscribe(
        (response :any )=> {
          console.log(response);
          }
        },
        (error :any ) => {
          this.error = true;
 this.errorMsg = error.error; // assigning server side errro to the variable.
        }
        );

  }

That's done.
```

Comment: Thanks Kamaal.  This will work.  I was hoping for something generic that could work with all forms.  So if I have a form with 20 inputs then the errors are mapped automatically from the returned object to the form.  If an item exists in the returned object then it is an error and the message must appear next to the box.  Is there some package or something that will allow server validation errors to be shown onto the form.  I was hoping to also have the validation hook into the angular validation and not have to manage the errors myself, by using the form.control.valid property.